How many moderators are we electing?
I can't find the number of moderator posts that are being filled by the election that is currently in progress. I'm sure it is my fault, but I feel that I really need to know that before I vote.
I also hope this is the right place to ask the question. If it isn't, I would appreciate knowing where I should ask it.

The election page says "positions 1" in the top right corner.

@NotThatGuy As so often, it was under my nose. Thanks very much.

The number of positions is displayed in the top right corner of the election page. See the screenshot below (created on a narrow browser screen).


Thanks very much. Specially for the mini-screenshot.
